# issue with Apache and CGI script

Tags: apache-2.4, cgi

I have one interesting issue with Apache and CGI scripts.

When I make request to CGI script in following format: `/cgi-bin/myscript.sh/myscript.params`, apache firstly checks that there allowed query to `/cgi-bin/myscript.sh/myscript.params` - it's expected behaviour, but after it he trims `/cgi-bin/myscript.sh` part and check only `"/myscript.params"`.

How I can disable that second check?

Dump from debug log:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10204] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10204] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[core:trace3] [pid 10204] request.c(227): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /cgi-bin/myscript.sh/myscript.params
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10204] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10204] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[core:trace3] [pid 10204] request.c(227): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /myscript.params
[cgi:trace4] [pid 10204] util_script.c(521): [client 127.0.0.1:50196] Headers from script 'myscript.sh':
```